# Unable to load class on jibX binding compilation

Tags: java, xml, jibx

Hi I'm new to JibX and just started with a sample. on running the binding compiler in command prompt , it throws the below error,

C:\Users\Uvais\JavaProject\src\com\jibX>java -jar C:\Drive\jibx_1_2_6\jibx\lib\jibx-bind.jar binding.xml
Error: Unable to load class com.jibX.Person; on structure element at (l
ine 3, col 50, in binding.xml)
Error running binding compiler
org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: Binding binding.xml is unusable because of valid
ation errors
        at org.jibx.binding.Utility.loadBinding(Utility.java:358)
        at org.jibx.binding.Utility.loadFileBinding(Utility.java:420)
        at org.jibx.binding.Compile.compile(Compile.java:217)
        at org.jibx.binding.Compile.main(Compile.java:384)

below is my binding.xml

```
<binding>
<mapping name="customer" class="Customer" ordered="false">
    <structure name="person" field="person" >
        <value name="cust-num" field="customerNumber" usage="optional"/>
    </structure>
    <value name="street" field="street" />
</mapping>
```

But im able to compile the same in eclipse and also in command prompt if i comment the structure tag in binding.xml. Kindly helpfor the same. and it will be veryuseful, if any one can share a nice tutorial on JibX for beginners,

Answer (score 0):

Mohamed,

It looks like you may have a problem with the case on your package name. Remember windows files system is not case sensitive, but Java is.

The class com.jibX.Person should probably be com.jibx.Person.

Why don't you start with one of the simple maven-based samples. You'll find them here:

http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven-jibx-plugin/index.html

There are also some nice examples in the github repo. This one is pretty simple:

https://github.com/jibx/maven-plugin/tree/master/test-suite/base-binding-test

Good Luck!

Don

Comment: even changing jibX to jibx has the same problem.